# How to consume a SOAP (WCF) service in Plone?

Tags: soap, plone

Im very new to Plone, having only really scratched the surface of the product.

My client uses it, and would like an application built using it.

Can anyone give me some pointers on how to consume a SOAP service in Plone?

Any links to tutorials, articles, screencasts etc would be apprciated.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

For a good Python SOAP client to use with Plone, we usually recommend Suds: https://fedorahosted.org/suds/